# Time and space complexity of the two different approaches

Tags: javascript, big-o

I am trying to learn how to estimate time and space complexity of different iterations and need some help with my second approach. What's the difference in terms of space & time complexity on those two functions below?

This should be `O(n)` time and `O(n)` space.

```js
function twoNumberSum(array, targetSum) {
  let nums = {};

  for (const num of array) {
    const potentialMatch = targetSum - num;

    if (potentialMatch in nums) {
      return [potentialMatch, num].sort((a, b) => a - b)
    } else {
      nums[num] = true
    }
  }

  return []
}

console.log(twoNumberSum([3, 5, -4, 8, 11, 1, -1, 6], 10))
```

However, this approach?

```js
function twoNumberSum(array, targetSum) {
  const map = new Map(array.map(item => [item, item]));

  for (let [key, value] of map) {
    const missingInc = targetSum - value;
    if (missingInc !== value && map.has(missingInc)) {
      return [value, map.get(missingInc)].sort((a, b) => a - b)
    }
  }

  return [];
}

console.log(twoNumberSum([3, 5, -4, 8, 11, 1, -1, 6], 10))
```

Also, final question... when I sort the return statement with `.sort((a, b) => a - b)` should this be defined as `O(log(n))`?

Comment: Both are O(n) time and O(n) space. Since you only return the first pair found the added (negligible) complexity for is O(2) (one comparison + one switch).

Comment: Thanks, that really helped me understanding better @Bergi

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest to first refactor them to use the same data structure, so that differences become more visible:

```
function twoNumberSum(array, targetSum) {
  let nums = new Set();
  for (const num of array) {
    const potentialMatch = targetSum - num;
    if (nums.has(potentialMatch) {
      return [potentialMatch, num].sort((a, b) => a - b)
    } else {
      nums.add(num)
    }
  }
  return []
}
```

```
function twoNumberSum(array, targetSum) {
  const nums = new Set();
  for (const num of array)
    nums.add(num);
  // alternatively, use const nums = new Set(array), but the loop is clearer
  for (let num of array) {
    const missingInc = targetSum - num;
    if (missingInc !== value && nums.has(missingInc)) {
      return [value, missingInc].sort((a, b) => a - b)
    }
  }
  return [];
}
```

Before considering performance, we need to evaluate the correctness/equivalence: notice that the second function doesn't work when the input value contains duplicates. But let's assume that this is given as a precondition (can never happen), in which case the results are always the same.

The difference is that one approach always constructs the whole lookup map before testing values, while the other builds it on the go. While both have `O(n)` worst case complexity, the best case complexity for the first approach is `O(1)` while it is `O(n)` for the second. What the *average* complexity is depends on how your inputs are distributed.

> When I sort the return statement with `.sort((a, b) => a - b)` should this be defined as `O(log(n))`?

No. The complexity of a sort is generally `O(n log n)`, but where `n` refers to the length of the array to be sorted. In your case, you're always sorting an array of two items, which has constant complexity. It does not depend on the size of your input `n` (assumed to be the `array.length`, although in some numerical problems you also need to consider the size of the numbers).